# ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Whisper'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Here is my models.py

```
  class RUDevice(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(_("Device Name"), max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, help_text="Device Name", default='')
        last_active = models.DateTimeField(_("Last Active"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, 

class Magazine(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(RUDevice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, related_name='ru_magazine' )
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, related_name='magazine_product_type')

class MagazineProduct(models.Model):
    magazine = models.ForeignKey(Magazine, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, related_name='magazine_product', help_text="Select magazine for product")

class ProductType(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(ProductCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, related_name='company', help_text="Select company name")
    size = models.ForeignKey(ProductSize, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, related_name='type_class', help_text="Select product class")

class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(_("SKU"), max_length=100, blank=True, unique=True,help_text="Store ID")
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, related_name='product_type', help_text="Select product type")
    count= models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class SingleProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='product', help_text="Select product")
```

I am trying to filter rudevices with specific brand. it will return all the rurudevices that's magazine has this brand.
my first approach was this.

```
for i in RUDevice.objects.all():
    mg = Magazine.objects.filter(device=i)
```

then filter all MagazineProduct with all the returned mg.
        `MagazineProduct.objects.filter(magazine__in=mg, magazine__product_type__brand="Whisper")`

if i can filter magazineProduct then i can get rudevices . But i am getting `ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Whisper'.`
and is my apporach ok?

Comment: It's hard to tell what your data model is all about. Why is there a `SingleProduct` that only has a foreign key to a Product, for instance? Can a Magazine really only refer to a single Device? Etc.

Comment: I have other fields. with SingleProduct. i posted this way for simplicity. All i want is filter by brand and show rudevices has this product brand.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, it expects an integer value or an object. But if you are searching with a string, probably that is against a field. Assuming it is a `name` then you can try like this:

```
MagazineProduct.objects.filter(
    magazine__device=i,
    magazine__product_type__brand__name="Whisper"
)
```

I have removed `mg` and directly using `i` inside the `MagazineProduct`.